# How to validate the length of character is equals to 5 using express-validator?

Tags: html, node.js, express, express-validator

I am planning to make partnerid field character length as 5 which means user will get error message if he enters less than 5 character or more than 5 characters which will include alpha-numeric character. 
How can we do it using express-validator?
I tried using below code but it didn't worked
Thanks

```
   req.checkBody('partnerid', 'Partnerid field must be 5 character long ').len(5);
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use `isLength()` option of the `express-validator` to check `max` and `min` length of `5`:

```
 req.checkBody('partnerid', 'Partnerid field must be 5 character long ').isLength({ min: 5, max:5 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `matches` option of `express-validator` to check if the partner field only contains **alphanumeric** and has a length of 5

```
req.checkBody('partnerid', 'Partnerid field must be 5 character long ').matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}$/, "i");
```

Answer (score 0):

`.len(5)` not support in express validation, you can use `.isLength(5)` to check for a max and min length of 5.

```
req.checkBody('partnerid', 'Partnerid field must be 5 character long strong text').isLength(5);
```